# how to find a string in another one without using find() method in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
def light(): 
    result = collection1.find({"deviceName":    })
    lights_id = []
    for x in result:
       lights_id.append(x["_id"])
    return lights_id
```

I need to fetch in a database for a device name containing the string light, and I need to fill it in the blank but I don't know how to do it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `collecyion1` is a mongodb collection, i think this should work

```
collection1.find({'deviceName': {'$regex': ".*light.*", '$options': 'i'}})
```

as mongodb supports regex, we are searching a text using regex in this case
`./*light.*` and passing option `i` so that the match is case insensetive.

Comment: well it is giving an error ```SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` for this```/``` @mursalin

Comment: can you try {'deviceName': {'$regex': ".*light.*", '$options': 'i'}} and see if that works?

Comment: It worked well thank you!! But can I know more about what you did? Is it related to a regular expression in python? @mursalin and thanks again

Comment: @Jenny I don't know why the previous one didn't work, I have updated the answer. can you please accept it as correct.